# Use CDK deploy time token values in a launch template user-data script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I recently starting porting part of my infrastructure to AWS CDK. Previously, I did some experiments with Cloudformation templates directly.

I am currently facing the problem that I want to encode some values (namely the product version) in a user-data script of an EC2 launch template and these values should only be loaded at deployment time. With Cloudformation this was quite simple, I was just building my JSON file from functions like `Fn::Base64` and `Fn::Join`. E.g. it looked like this (simplified)

```json
"MyLaunchTemplate": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate",
        "Properties": {
            "LaunchTemplateData": {
                "ImageId": "ami-xxx",
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "#!/bin/bash -xe",
                            {"Fn::Sub": "echo \"${SomeParameter}\""},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I am able to define the parameter `SomeParameter` on launch of the cloudformation template.

With CDK we can access values from the AWS Parameter Store [either at deploy time or at synthesis time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/get_ssm_value.html). If we use them at deploy time, we only get a token, otherwise we get the actual value.

I have achieved so far to read a value for synthesis time and directly encode the user-data script as base64 like this:

```py
product_version = ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(
    self, f'/Prod/MyProduct/Deploy/Version')

launch_template = ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(self, 'My-LT', launch_template_data={
    'imageId': my_ami,
    'userData': base64.b64encode(
        f'echo {product_version}'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'),
})
```

With this code, however, the version gets read during synthesis time and will be hardcoded into the user-data script.

In order to be able to use dynamic values that are only resolved at deploy time (`value_for_string_parameter`) I would somehow need to tell CDK to write a Cloudformation template similar to what I have done manually before (using `Fn::Base64` only in Cloudformation, not in Python). However, I did not find a way to do this.

If I read a value that is only to be resolved at deploy time like follows, how can I use it in the `UserData` field of a launch template?

```
latest_string_token = ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter(
    self, "my-plain-parameter-name", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the Cloudformation intrinsic functions which are available [in the class `aws_cdk.core.Fn` in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Fn.html).

These can be used when creating a launch template in EC2 to combine strings and tokens, [e.g. like this](https://blog.stefan-koch.name/2021/09/22/aws-cdk-deployment-time-variables-parameter-store-launch-template-user-data):

```py
import aws_cdk.core as cdk

# loads a value to be resolved at deployment time
product_version = ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter(
    self, '/Prod/MyProduct/Deploy/Version')

launch_template = ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(self, 'My-LT', launch_template_data={
    'imageId': my_ami,
    'userData': cdk.Fn.base64(cdk.Fn.join('\n', [
        '#!/usr/bin/env bash',
        cdk.Fn.join('=', ['MY_PRODUCT_VERSION', product_version]),
        'git checkout $MY_PRODUCT_VERSION',
    ])),
})
```

This example could result in the following user-data script in the launch template if the parameter store contains version `1.2.3`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MY_PRODUCT_VERSION=1.2.3
git checkout $MY_PRODUCT_VERSION
```

Comment: In my case `cdk.Fn.join('\n',[....])` prints `\n`, but not newline (Typescript)

Comment: @AndreyZentavr Some languages treat escape characters specially, for example in Ruby `'\n'` means *backslash-n*, whereas `"\n"` means *newline*. I do not know TypeScript, but might be similar for that language.